# Let $k$ be a field and $V$ a $k$-vector space of infinite dimension, then $V$ and $V^{*}$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and consider $\lbrace A_i \rbrace _{i\in I}$ with $A_i\in Obj(\mathcal{C})$ and coproduct $(\amalg _{i\in I} A_i,\phi_i)$. Using the following bijection
>   $$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(\coprod_{i\in I} A_i,B)\cong \prod_{i \in I}\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A_i,B)$$
>   which is functorial on $B$, and using the fact that, given an arbitrary set $I$ and a field $k$ it follows that $\dim_k(k^{I})= |k|^{|I|}$, prove the following:
>
> If $k$ is a field and $V$ a $k$-vector of infinite dimension, then $V$ and $V^{*}=\text{Hom}_{k}(V,k)$ are not isomorphic.

My attempt:

Let $k$ be a field, then we take $\mathcal{C}$ as the category of vector spaces over $k$. Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space of infinite dimension. Let $A=\lbrace a_i \rbrace_{i\in I}$ be a $k$-basis for $V$. Then we know that
$$V\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I} k$$
Now, in this category we have that the coproduct is the direct sum. So we can write 
$$V\cong \coprod_{i\in I} k$$
Taking a look at 
$$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(\coprod_{i\in I} A_i,B)\cong \prod_{i \in I}\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A_i,B)$$
We realize that if we take $A_i=k$ for all $i$ and $B=k$, then we would have
$$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(\coprod_{i\in I} k,k)\cong \prod_{i \in I}\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(k,k)$$
Which is now equivalent to
$$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,k)\cong \prod_{i \in I}\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(k,k)$$
And so $V^{*} \cong \prod_{i \in I}\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(k,k)$. Now, we know that for a given vector space $V$ over $k$ with $k$-basis $\lbrace v_i \rbrace_{i\in I}$, we have that $\text{End}(V) \cong \bigoplus_{i\in I} V$. Since $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(k,k) = \text{End}(k)$ and $k$ is just $k$ as a vector space over $k$, then $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(k,k) \cong k$, and so, $\cong \prod_{i \in I}\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(k,k) \cong k^I$, which gives us $V^{*} \cong K^I$.

Now, we have $|V^{*}|=|k|^{|I|}$, and we know that for an vector space over $k$, we have $|V|=|k|·\text{dim}(V)$ and $\text{dim}(V) = |A|=|I|$, and so for any $k$-vector space different than $k$, we would have
$$|V|=|k|·|I|$$
$$|V^{*}|=|k|^{|I|}$$
from which it follows that $V$ and $V^{*}$ could never be isomorphic. Is this a correct reasoning?

I would also want to understand what is the role of ***functorial on B*** in this context. Also, I'm not sure if I'm missing something yet to check, is there anything else that I should see for the reasoning to be complete?

Thanks in advice for the replies.

Comment: Well, the obvious next question is: what is $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(k,k)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey it's just $k$, I've updated the post with the progress I made.

Comment: This is now a very complete proof. The functoriality of the isomorphism isn't relevant here.